# How to use ggplot geom_ribbon to reference data subset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to add a ribbon-style error bar to the line in this plot:
[image]

Because the plot is a combination point and line graph, I had to set up the ggplot script in a way that I found a bit confusing, but ultimately worked:

```
plot <-
  ggplot(NULL, aes(x = Year, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(data = point_data_melt) + 
  geom_line(data = line_data_melt) +
  ylab("δ18O‰") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") 
print(plot)
```

where point_data_melt and line_data_melt are both set up in the format:

| Year | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1981 | line_o18 | 24.1 |
| 1982 | line_o18 | 22.1 |
| 1983 | line_o18 | 23.9 |

etc.

I have another set of data to use as the error for each year (ex: min and max for 1981, min and max for 1982, etc). I'm attempting to use geom_ribbon to accomplish this:

```
geom_ribbon(data = line_error_melt, aes(ymin = (variable == min), ymax = (variable == max))
```

However, this understandably doesn't work. My question is -- how can I best set up my line_error_melt dataframe to accomplish what I'm after?

Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: Without a reproducible example one can only guess but from the info you provided you need a data.frame with columns Year, variable, min, max. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data(sets) shared using `dput()` so that we can run your code.

Comment: `geom_ribbon(data = line_error_melt, aes(ymin = min, ymax = max)` *might* work but, as @stefan has written, without a reproducible example, we cannot be sure.  As an aside, using base function names (`min` and `max`) as column names is not a good idea